# RuntimeException - Class XSLTProcessor does not exist - magento 2

Tags: magento, exception, runtime, magento2

I am receiving this error. I tried with the followings:

[image: error while compile]

1. Changing the file permission in `generated` folder
2. Tried removing `cache` and `page_cache` in `var` folder
3. Then tried removing `generated` folder as well

Then once I run the `php -dmemory_limit=10G bin/magento setup:di:compile` I am receiving this error code.

How can I fix this please?

Comment: composer update does that work?

Comment: @Rustyjim Nope. di:compile break the process.

Comment: Ah too bad , possibly file permissions then. See this post. https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Running-di-compile-stops-at-57/td-p/448128